# Find dates between start date and end date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, between

I got 2 columns, one is start date and the other is end date. I need to find every single day between the two dates.

Need it in another table with two coloums, one name `pno` that refers to the `pno`'s id in the first table, and the other with the dates between start date and end date.

As an example this could be my input

```
 
pno         startdate        end date
p1          2012-12-03      2012-12-06     
p2          2013-01-05      2013-01-08
p3          2013-01-15      2012-01-20
```

and this has to be my output.

```
pno          dates
----------
p01          2012-12-03 
p01          2012-12-04 
p01          2012-12-05 
p01          2012-12-06
p02          2013-01-05
p02          2013-01-06
p02          2013-01-07
p02          2013-01-08
p03          2013-01-15
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT pno, startdate + INTERVAL q.n - 1 DAY dates
  FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) q 
 WHERE q.n - 1 <= DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate) 
 ORDER BY pno, dates
```

The subquery generates a sequence of numbers from 1 to 100. You can adjust it for your needs (if date differences span more or less than 100 days) or completely substitute it with a persisted tally(numbers) table if you do a lot of such queries.

Output:

```
+------+------------+
| pno  | dates      |
+------+------------+
| p1   | 2012-12-03 |
| p1   | 2012-12-04 |
| p1   | 2012-12-05 |
| p1   | 2012-12-06 |
| p2   | 2013-01-05 |
| p2   | 2013-01-06 |
| p2   | 2013-01-07 |
| p2   | 2013-01-08 |
| p3   | 2013-01-15 |
| p3   | 2013-01-16 |
| p3   | 2013-01-17 |
| p3   | 2013-01-18 |
| p3   | 2013-01-19 |
| p3   | 2013-01-20 |
+------+------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f29c4/5)** demo

---

**UPDATE:** To create and populate persisted tally table use

```
CREATE TABLE tally (n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO tally (n)
SELECT a.n + b.n * 10 + c.n * 100 + d.n * 1000 + 1 n
 FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
,(SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
,(SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
,(SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) d
ORDER BY n;
```

You'll have in the tally table sequence of numbers from 1 to 10000. That will allow you to work with date ranges that span more than 27 years.

Now the query boils down to

```
SELECT pno, startdate + INTERVAL q.n - 1 DAY dates
  FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN tally q 
 WHERE q.n - 1 <= DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate) 
 ORDER BY pno, dates
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/308f1/1)** demo

Comment: for the dates with a span of more than 2 years

Comment: @user2825758 See updated answer and sqlfiddle example. Create a persisted tally(numbers) table with provided script and use it. IMHO it's **the fastest and generic way** to work with date ranges. Any other approache will require to use a stored routine to be able to use loops and will be way slower and way less flexible.